# how to automatic fiil the child on firebase with Android studio

Tags: android, firebase

i am using android studio. i want to change "Checkin" on "room" child if date of checkin same with date of system. i have already take date from system. but how the code . for automatic change "Checkin" on "room" child. where "Checkin" on child booking same with date of system...

[image: this is my structure on firebase]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childEventListener` to get all child of a node in Firebase database, childEventListener will be triggered at the first time attached to a database reference and triggered again when child of the node of the reference added, changed, removed,... In your case, assume you have already defined `Room` class with those attributes you can add listener for you database as below:

```
String systemTime = "HH-MM-SS"; //your system time
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Room room = dataSnapshot.getValue(Room.class);
        if(room.checkin.equals(systemTime))
        {
            //do something with the room
            //then new value back
            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(room);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
root.child("booking").addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Visit this link to get more information about working with list in firebase database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data